# How to find record Id in service console?

Tags: service-cloud-console

If I use Salesforce classic, I can find record Id in url. Is there any way to find record Id when I am in console?

Comment: From Dev Console?

Comment: @PhilHawthorn service console

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Click on triangle in right upper corner and click 'Get link to share'.

Comment: Thank you! Really helpful!

Answer (score 1):

Getting Id visually: bring up the URL-grabber using the triangle tab as MrKonyk says, or using the keyboard shortcut U (assuming that you've enabled keyboard shortcuts in your console app's configuration, and typed 'Esc' once to enable the shortcuts for yourself as user).

Getting Id for use in code: use the methods in the [Salesforce Console Integration Toolkit](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api_console.meta/api_console/sforce_api_console_intro.htm) such as [getFocusedPrimaryTabObjectId()](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api_console.meta/api_console/sforce_api_console_intro.htm)